# Python logarithm function and select point above that log line

Tags: python, pandas, math, logarithm

I am trying to create a log function to display on my graph such as a log(x, 0.5)

[image]

I started creating a line

```
def f(x):
    return np.int(x)
f2 = np.vectorize(f)
x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
plt.plot(-x+100, f2(x))
plt.show()
```

[image: linspace]

and then I would like to convert it to a log and display in a matplot plt.

I want to use this log function to create a division on my data, so I can pick the one that are above this line.

but when I use

```
x = math.log(x,1/2)
```

I receive

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 1):

`math.log` is a scalar function.  To operate on a vector (NumPy array), use `np.log`.  You adjust the base with the well-known algebraic formula.

```
x = np.log(x) / math.log(0.5)
```

Comment: `TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType`




with 




`y = np.linspace(100, 0, num=100, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=int, axis=0)` \n

`x = np.log(y, 0.5)`

Comment: My apologies; I neglected to look up the doc for numpy.log